# Casting Foo<Bar> to Foo<AnyObject> and vice versa

Tags: ios, swift

I have problem with type conversion from Foo<'AnyObject'> to Foo<'Bar'>.

```
static func castToChannelViewModel(data: [CategoriesSectionInfo<AnyObject>]) {
    var result = [CategoriesSectionInfo<ChannelViewModel>]()

    for item in data {
        if item is CategoriesSectionInfo<ChannelViewModel> {
            result.append(item as CategoriesSectionInfo<ChannelViewModel>)
        }
    }
}
```

And I've got error like this even if I check that this type is correct:

Cannot convert value of type CategoriesSectionInfo<'AnyObject'> to type 'CategoriesSectionInfo<'ChannelViewModel'> in coercion

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't. At least I did not figure out how. 
(You cannot do similar things in Java too, but there you could use `Foo<T extends Bar>` )

Try this

```
let cannelViewModel = CategoriesSectionInfo<ChannelViewModel>(item)
```

or

```
result.append(CategoriesSectionInfo<ChannelViewModel>(item))
```

respectively.

You may have to give some prefix followed by : before `item`. Xcode will give you some hint.